# Install Ubuntu in Windows 10 (Lenovo Z-40 Laptop)

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows, uefi, windows-8

I was trying to install Ubuntu as a dual boot option from my usb disk but every-time i tried i failed. I went to UEFI mode of windows. Then I disabled the Widnows secure boot option and selected the primary boot as USB. However it starts the windows again rather booting from USB. I tried multiple times but run out of luck. Any suggestion? I really appreciate your help .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the recommend program to write ISO to USB from the ubuntu download page ?

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Trying going back into your bios and set it to default, you don't need to change the boot priorities. Once your lenovo reboots, hit the "enter" key and then a blue dialog box should be present. Scroll down to the option which states something along the lines "boot from other / change device".

From there you should see all the available devices to boot from, try the first usb option, if it doesn't work, repeat the steps and select the 2nd usb option.

*I currently have a lenovo T430s running 14.04.3LTS

Comment: I followed the same steps explained in the link to create ISO to USB. I did in the same way you explained and failed. Thus i changed the boot priorities since some other people suggested me in that way..

Answer (score 0):

USB devices require the boot loader to be stored as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` on a FAT partition. This is the "fallback filename" for EFI-mode booting; it's what the firmware looks for when a boot loader entry is not present in NVRAM (as when booting an OS installer). A standard Ubuntu installation, OTOH, makes the assumption that it's installing to a hard disk, and that it can store a boot loader path in NVRAM, so it doesn't use the fallback filename, and instead installs GRUB as `EFI/ubuntu/grubx.64.efi` on the [EFI System Partition (ESP),](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and stores Shim (used for Secure Boot compatibility) as `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`.

To get your USB installation to boot, you must mount its FAT partition (ESP) and rename `EFI/ubuntu` on it to `EFI/BOOT`, then rename `shimx64.efi` in that directory to `bootx64.efi`. (If you want to boot without Secure Boot, you could instead rename `grubx64.efi` to `bootx64.efi`; but renaming Shim should also work in this case.)

Note that these filenames assume an x86-64/AMD64 (64-bit) system and installation. 32-bit EFI installations are rare, but require changing `x64` to `ia32` in all filenames.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Your response seems reasonable.. Currently I am trying in your way and leave feedback soon.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am using Ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.While I am entering my USB disk I can see EFI Folder and it contains BOOT folder and by default it has BOOTx64.EFI and grubx64.efi File. So recent UBUNTU installation doen't require modifications.. I don't know why still I am failing and all the time windows loads automatically :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to boot menú, to access turn off laptop ande select button next to the power charger slot and one time in boot menú disable legacy on boot and change to UEFI. Save changes and reboot the will appear Ubuntu startup menu.